# Populating subclasses in Jooq

Tags: java, jooq

I have the following Java class:

```
public class Font {

   private String fontFamily;

   private int fontSize;

   // other members and getters/setters
}
```

The Font class is used in this class:

```
public class RichText {

   private int code;

   private String richString;

   private Font titleFont;

   private Font subtitleFont;

   // other members and getters/setters
}
```

Now, I have a single table in the database to store `RichText`, note that I flattened the font classes to avoid creating an additional table:

```
CREATE TABLE rich_text (

   code int,

   rich_string text,

   fontTitleFamily varchar(20),

   fontTitleSize int,

   fontSubtitleFamily varchar(20),

   fontSubtitleSize int,

   .....

);
```

I read the `rich_text` table using Jooq like so:

```
    Record rec = create.select()
            .from(RICH_TEXT)
            .where(RICH_TEXT.CODE.eq(code))
            .fetchAny();

    if (rec == null)
        throw new RecordNotFoundException();

    RichText richText = new RichText();
    rec.into(richText);
```

But this doesn't populate the font classes because the names are different. I don't want to normalize this table as it will only have two fonts.

Is there a way in Jooq to annotate or to configure in the generator the relationship between the columns in the database and the fields of a subclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`RecordMapper`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual-single-page/#recordmapper) to customize how you want your classes to be mapped from a record, I don't know how your constructors look like, but an inline example could be:

```
RichText richText = create.select()
            .from(RICH_TEXT)
            .where(RICH_TEXT.CODE.eq(code))
            .fetchOne(new RecordMapper<Record, RichText>() {

                @Override
                public RichText map(Record record) {

                    RichText richText = new RichText(
                            record.get(RICH_TEXT.CODE),
                            record.get(RICH_TEXT.RICH_STRING ),
                            new Font(
                                record.get(RICH_TEXT.FONTTITLEFAMILY), 
                                record.get(RICH_TEXT.FONTTITLESIZE)
                            ),
                            new Font(
                                record.get(RICH_TEXT.FONTSUBTITLEFAMILY), 
                                record.get(RICH_TEXT.FONTSUBTITLESIZE)
                            )

                        );

                    return richText;

                }
            });
```

I typed this on the fly, so its possible that I got some field name wrong.

You can also set a custom [`RecordMapperProvider`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual-single-page/#pojos-with-recordmapper-provider) to return you custom `RecordMapper` in the Jooq configuration.

Comment: This worked. Since I don't have a constructor in this class, I used `record.into(richText)` and then set the fonts the way you did. Also, instead of using an anonymous class I created a new one that's reusable.

Comment: Is there a similar mapper for `insert`s instead of `read`s? I couldn't find it

Comment: Yes, there is an interface `RecordUnmapper` and also a `RecordUnmapperProvider`, it does the same but in the other direction, from POJO to record, looking at the docs I couldn't find it either, but I know it's there.

Comment: Can you please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54798190/how-to-use-jooq-recordunmapper)?

Comment: @ps0604 You should not use the coments to ask for review of some other questions you have, You need to be patient, I am sure someone will answer your question anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lesser known feature of the [`DefaultRecordMapper`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DefaultRecordMapper.html), the ability to map into nested types. This will require aliasing all of your columns of the nested values:

```
RichText result = create
    .select(
         RICH_TEXT.CODE,
         RICH_TEXT.RICH_STRING,
         RICH_TEXT.FONTTITLEFAMILY.as("titleFont.fontFamily"),
         RICH_TEXT.FONTTITLESIZE.as("titleFont.fontSize"),
         RICH_TEXT.FONTSUBTITLEFAMILY.as("subtitleFont.fontFamily"),
         RICH_TEXT.FONTSUBTITLESIZE.as("subtitleFont.fontSize"),
         ...)
    .from(RICH_TEXT)
    .where(RICH_TEXT.CODE.eq(code))
    .fetchAnyInto(RichText.class);
```

A future version of jOOQ will allow for specifying something similar like JPA's `@Embeddable` types, which will then automate the above for all queries: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2530