# How to use jOOQ RecordUnmapper?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I'm trying to implement a jOOQ `RecordUnmapper` to adjust a record that I will later insert/update.

My attempt below, problem is that the `Record` class cannot be instantiated. How to create the `Record` object?  Also, how to use the unmapper in insert/update?

```java
public class TableUnmapper implements RecordUnmapper<Table, Record> {

    @Override
    public Record unmap(Table t) throws MappingException {
        Record r = new Record();  // <-- this line does not compile
        r.from(t);
        r.set(TABLES.TITLE_FONT_FAMILY, t.getTitleFont().getFontFamily());
        return r;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Record` is an interface, so you can't directly create an instance of the interface, you have to instantiate a class that implements the `Record` interface, if you use Jooq code generator, you probably already have a `TableRecord` class, this is the class you can use for this purpouse,

then the unmapper should look something like:

```
public class TableUnmapper implements RecordUnmapper<Table, TableRecord> {

    @Override
    public TableRecord unmap(Table t) throws MappingException {

        TableRecord r = new TableRecord(t.getSomeAttribute());

        r.setAttribute(t.getSomeOtherAttribute());

        return r;
    }

}
```

To use the unmapper:

```
DSLContext create;
Table table = new Table(/* Whatever Arguments */);
TableUnmapper unmapper = new TableRecordUnmapper();

// Insert
create.insertInto(TABLES).set(unmapper.unmap(table));

// update
create.executeUpdate(unmapper.unmap(table));
```

Comment: Also, if there's no specific (generated) record type available, records can be created by using [`DSLContext.newRecord()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#newRecord-org.jooq.Field...-)